# How do I get the Azure authorization code in a python CLI application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-cli

I am writing a python command line application that requires the user to authenticate themselves against Azure using the "Authorization Flow".  This requires that I call the Azure MSAL python method "acquire_token_by_authorization_code".  This method takes an "authorization code" as input, however, I'm not clear on how to get the authorization code.  This requires the user to authenticate themselves through a web browser just like the "az login" command line program works and I assume that the code is returned once the user authenticates themself. I'm not clear on how to get that authorization code within my python program.  I have a reference to a sort of [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp/blob/7131808b90b90f1c6ef6ea0d8a0e2a9b3606c9b2/app.py).  However, this is a Flask example and I'm not using Flask and am unclear on how to get the authorization code.

Answer (score 0):

**authorization_code:** When you request the `/authorize` endpoint to authorize the user that signs in, it will return `code` after succeeding authorization. You could refer to this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) about requesting an authorization code.

**Flow chart of using authorization code flow to call Microsoft Graph:**

[image]

In Python, [`acquire_token_with_authorization_code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/adal/adal.authentication_context.authenticationcontext?view=azure-python#acquire-token-with-authorization-code-authorization-code--redirect-uri--resource--client-id--client-secret-none--code-verifier-none-) gets a token for a given resource via authorization code for a server app.

This [sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/website_sample.py) uses website to get authorization_code, you could refer to it.